# intelXDK facebook object uncaught implementation

Tags: facebook-login, intel-xdk

I have followed the code sample from intelxdk on Facebook object login.
But I couldn't make the facebook login to work and when I check on the console log, it throws Uncaught not implemented error.

Has anyone successfully implemented the facebook login in intelXDK?

Answer (score 0):

Question is from long ago, but just thought I'd mention for future readers that the Intel XDK specific facebook implementation has been deprecated.  At this time, the 2 proposed solutions are:

1. https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin
2. https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB